# pgpool2 cannot rejoin faild master as the new slave

Tags: postgresql-9.1, pgpool

i have a pgpool2 3.1.3 installed with 2 postgresql 9.1.3 backend configured as master/slave with streaming replication.
If the master fails everything is ok, the slave takes over and becomes the new master.
The problem is that if i want to rejoin the old master in the cluster this is added as master also instead of slave.
I use pgpooladmin Version 3.1.1.
any idea ?

Comment: Are you using pgpool for the replication or the streaming replication built in to PostgreSQL itself?  (Or something else, like slony, etc.?)

Comment: i was using streaming replication build in postgres.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem. When i first created the streaming replication i configured postgresql as in streaming replication tutorial. Here the slave and master had different settings activated in config file, and this was the problem.
After i read one more time the pgpool2 multi server tutorial i found that in the first stage both servers have the same setup, and the slave would be started through pgpool.
After i corrected that everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully attached old master, then detaching new master wouldn't trigger old master get promoted again?

http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html#pcp_detach_node